# Bitcoin Private Key Decryption

Tags: bitcoin-core, private-key, wallet.dat, encryption

At present, I have dumped my wallet and have all private key, address information. I am now wanting to understand the decryption process for the private keys within the wallet. I have completed the following so far as stated in the comments - bitcoin source code (crytper.h/.cpp)

```
Wallet Private Keys are then encrypted using AES-256-CBC
```

* with the double-sha256 of the public key as the IV, and the
 * master key's key as the encryption key

So, my data looks this way:
    E Private Key (96)
    IV Public Key (8)
    U Master Key  (16)
I am using https://www.devglan.com/online-tools/aes-encryption-decryption for the decryption. When I use this site, my answer is not the private key which I know but rather data that is 32 bits longer than the encrypted key. Has anyone tried to figure the path for the keys? If so, what am I doing wrong? Thanks for all your help.

Comment: If you ran `dumpwallet` or `dumpprivkey`, the keys are already decrypted and are in Wallet Import Format, a base58 encoding of the 256-bit keys. You can import them directly into another wallet.

Comment: Thanks. This is not what we are trying to accomplish. We are checking the comments in the source code to verify this is the case as stated above.